# Considering air resistance is the force applied to lift an object equal to its weight?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, velocity, projectile, drag

Considering air resistance is the force applied to lift an object equal to its weight when the object moves at constant velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For certain velocities that could be the case. If you consider effect of air, then there are three forces at play:

1. Weight due to Earth, directed downwards
2. Air drag, which is usually proportional to speed, directed downwards in case of lifting
3. Buoyancy force or upthrust, directed upwards

If the density of the object is more than or equal to air's density, you could apply a force equal to the weight of the object for a certain velocity, where upthrust and drag would balance each other.
And if the density of the object is less than air's density, then upthrust is more than weight, so even here, if you apply a force equal to the weight of the body, after a certain time interval viscous force would increase in magnitude to balance the other forces, and velocity of object would become constant. This is known as terminal velocity.

But if we neglect the effect of buoyancy, then under no case would we apply a force equal to weight for constant velocity lifting.

Comment: Sir, I am a beginner learning basic physics at **https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class**   - website. So far I have not been introduced to this buoyancy concept so I am sure the author would have not considered it in his question - ( trying to answer an exercise question I asked you this doubt ). 6th question under check your understanding in this link - **https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/energy/Lesson-1/Calculating-the-Amount-of-Work-Done-by-Forces** for your reference

Comment: In the question you linked, air drag is not to be considered either. This is evident from the fact that coefficient of viscosity of air, $\eta$, has not been given to us. Here you have to consider the weight of the object as the only force acting on it, other than the external force supplied by you.

Comment: sir, what would be the situation if we consider air resistance???

Comment: As written in the last line of my answer, you will have to apply a force greater than weight, because both weight and air drag are directed downwards.

Comment: Thank You Sir, It was very helpful